# iomanip operations are returning a hex value

Tags: c++, string, double, currency, iomanip

I am trying to take a `double` and output it as currency by using `iomanip` and writing my own stream manipulator. I do so by writing a method which returns an ostream and takes an ostream as an argument (as well as two integer arguments, width and precision)

```
std::ostream& Currency(std::ostream& os, int width, int precision)
{
    os << "$";
    os << std::setprecision(precision);
    os << std::right;
    os << std::setw(width);
    os << std::fixed << std::setfill('0');
    return os;
}
```

However, instead of the output I'm expecting, `$0000128.00`, I get the output `$0x7ffeb45783d8128.00`.

I simply call it like so:

```
cout << Currency(cout, 11, 2) << balance << endl;
```

Not sure what the problem is, it seems to be something to do with it being wrapped in a function. If I copy the exact code not in a function to my actual output then it works perfectly.

Also before I run my Currency manipulator on the balance I also run:

```
out << std::right << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(10) << a.accountNo << " ";
out << std::setfill(' ') << std::left << std::setw(19) << a.name << " ";
out << std::setfill(' ') << std::left << std::setw(3) << a.sex << " ";
out << std::setfill(' ') << std::left << std::setw(10) << a.dob.toString() << " ";
out << std::setfill(' ') << std::left << std::setw(40) << a.address << " ";
```

Comment: You haven't also set `scientific` mode? Because `fixed` combined with `scientific` will show hex notation (see e.g. [this format flag reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags)).

Comment: Nope, see updated question though @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @Shazer2 surely you mean `Currency(cout, 11, 2) << balance << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << Currency(cout, 11, 2) << balance << endl;
```

After the execution of the `Currency` function you end up with something similar to:

```
cout << cout << balance << endl;
```

There is no overload to print an `ostream` but there is a conversion to `void*` intended to be used in a boolean context that kicks in and generates the printout you are getting